# Change format .fromnow() momentjs method after a certain time difference

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using the https://momentjs.com/ javascript library and i'm developing a web app where it has to compare the currently date and other date using the .fromNow() method, but all the results return results like 6 months, 8 months, 1 year.
I expected when the date differences have more than 6 months, it change the format of the result to Day/Month/Year (Ej. 06/06/2018).

Comment: Check if difference is 6 months yourself...then return the date format or fromNow result

Comment: Yes, i do it and run good but i think it could have a date property to configure that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly:

```
function myFromNow(date1, date2) {    
 if (date2.diff(date1, 'days') > 180) {
  return date1.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
 } else {
  return date1.from(date2);
 }
}
```